# Javascript: Execute python file (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: javascript, python, django, raspberry-pi, webserver

I got a Django Webserver running on my Raspberry Pi. I got an JavaScript file, where I want to execute a external python file to do something. I also want to give a value from JS to the python file.
How can I execute a python file from JavaScript and also, is there a way to set a parameter to the python file, which he receives from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**To pass arguments from js to python file, all you need is to make an ajax call, you can achieve that like**

JS Code

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/pythoncode.py",
  data: { param: text}
}).done(function( o ) {
   // do something
});
```

Comment: Does this also execute the file or is there a seperate command for that?